# Google Talk not working over Corporate Wifi. What can I do?

Tags: wi-fi, 3g, google-talk

Whenever I'm connected to our corporate wifi, google chat goes offline (i.e. the contact list fades to grey).

I think this is due to a port setting. As far as I know only 80 (http), 443 (ssl) and ftp (21) are allowed from inside my company.

The problem is, that my android device automatically turns off the 3g connection as soon as wifi is available.

I tried to find a setting for the Access Point, but couldn't find one. Likewise, I don't know if there is any setting in Google chat.

Android 2.2, LG-P500, Firmware V10-OCT-01-2010, Kernel 2.6.32.9

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Is turning off your Wifi and just using 3g an option?

Comment: well, no: I would still like to use Wifi for browsing since it is (most of the time) much faster. No way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The problem is, that my android device automatically turns off the 3g connection as soon as wifi is available.

Why don't you shut off Wi-Fi?

Since you can't control port forwarding or anything at work, there's not much else you can do.  Although, you could just ask and see whether they'd consider opening the Google Talk ports (443/5222/5223).

Comment: You may find this pedantic but I think that turning wifi off and on just to chat isn't a great solution... thanks for your answer though.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/Finding-Solutions/browse_thread/thread/b7915f18e94daecb?pli=1) Google Talk will attempt to connect over port 80 if it's other ports are blocked.

> Google Talk will work over port 80. If you are using the official 
>   client, it will even switch to trying 80 if the normal port (5222) is 
>   blocked.
>
> That said, if your employer is blocking talk.google.com instead of port 
>   5222, you'll probably find yourself up a creek. :)

Sounds like your best bet is to stop using their Wi-Fi and use 3G for connection to Google Talk.

Comment: I don't think the Android client would do this the same as the PC client.  I could be wrong though.

Comment: what if you need to use a proxy on your lan. does gtalk work via a proxy

Answer (score 1):

A lot of corporate networks block the 5XXX ports. I'm not entirely sure what Google Talk uses as I've read 5222 and 5228.

The Google Talk client for windows falls back to port 443 if the connection using port 5XXX is unsuccessful.

However the Android client does not do this. It only tries on port 5XXX.

Unfortunately at the moment the only solution is to contact your corporate IT and ask them to allow access using the 5XXX port.

Answer (score 1):

Google talk on the android phone only tries port 5222 and if it fails it will not try port 80 (as the specification requires).

But there is another answer:  [IMO](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.imo.android.imoim) (available on Google Play) works over port 80, so it will work behind a corporate firewall.  And it is a really good app.